# Why won't the table work for numbers 10, 11, and 12?

Tags: python-3.7

I want to write a program that simulates rolling two 6-sided dice 1000 times, and keeps track of how many times each sum occurs. Then my program should print out a table of the number of times it rolled each sum from 2 through 12.

I wrote some code that works for numbers 2 through 9, but for 10,11,12 nothing happens.

```
import random

results = []
for run in range(1000):
    rollTwoDice = random.randrange(1,6)+random.randrange(1,6)
    results += str(rollTwoDice)
print('Roll' + '    ' + 'Number')
print('----' + '    ' + '------')
for number in range(2,13):
    if number < 10:
        print(str(number) + '       ' + 
str(results.count(str(number))))
    else:
        print(str(number) + '       ')
```

It should output numbers in the number column next to rolls 10, 11, and 12.

Comment: You probably meant ```results.append(str(rollTwoDice)``` instead of ```results += str(rollTwoDice)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change random.randrange(1,6) to random.randrange(1,7) because 6 will never be generated in random.randrange(1, 6).

Comment: That just makes the person able to roll a 7, doesn't it?

Comment: @rm13 random.randrange(1,7) will return a random number from 1,6 inclusive. It will never return 7.

Comment: I tried that, but I still never got anything for numbers 10, 11, and 12.

Comment: @rm13 Make sure that you change 6 to 7 in both calls to random.randrange. Also, change 10 to 13 in if number < 10 because it is preventing the counts for numbers 10, 11, 12 from being printed.